# Center items correctly when using justify-content: space-between

Tags: html, css

I created a header bar and want to place 3 items there. The first should be aligned on the left side, the second in the middle of the header and the third on the right side.

I went for this

```css
body{
  background: #eeeeee;
}

#header {
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 53px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.headerEle {
  
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img class="headerEle" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/316916526760591362/390814093340311565/unknown.png">

  <a class="headerEle" href="https://www.google.de/">Google</a>

  <button class="headerEle">Logout</button>
</div>
```

but when using `justify-content: space-between;` the items don't get centered correctly. The image takes a bigger place than the small button on the right.

So the link in the middle is not centered correctly, it overlaps the right side. I want the link being in the horizontal center of the page.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: I think your demo is working as expected - there is equal spacing (around 172ish px) between all three elements. If you actually want them all to align central to their third of the space, just make them all 33% width with flex basis?

Comment: but as you can see the link is not placed in the center of the page, how can I fix this

Comment: The spacing is equal, i.e. it does what it has to, the point is in uneven width of the children (img, a, button).

Comment: so I have to put a div around each element and set the same width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

#header {
  background: #fff;
  height: 53px;
  display: flex;
  /*flex-direction: row; not necessary, by default*/
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#header > span {flex: 1} /* each 33.33% of the parent's width */

img {display: block; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100vh} /* responsiveness; "display: block" removes bottom margin/whitespace */

.link {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* horizontally centered */
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end; /* placed far right */
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <span>
    <img class="headerEle" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/316916526760591362/390814093340311565/unknown.png">
  </span>
  <span class="link">
    <a class="headerEle" href="https://www.google.de/">Google</a>
  </span>
  <span class="btn">
    <button class="headerEle">Logout</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use absolute positioning for the `<a>` element to exactly center the link on the header:

```css
body{
  background: #eeeeee;
}
#header {
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 53px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position:relative;
}
#header a {
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img class="headerEle" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/316916526760591362/390814093340311565/unknown.png">
  <a class="headerEle" href="https://www.google.de/">Google</a>
  <button class="headerEle">Logout</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking to do?

```css
body{
  background: #eeeeee;
}

#header {
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 53px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
#header > div {
    -webkit-flex: 1; /* Safari 6.1+ */
    -ms-flex: 1; /* IE 10 */
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div>
        <img class="headerEle" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/316916526760591362/390814093340311565/unknown.png">
    </div>
    <div>
        <a class="headerEle" href="https://www.google.de/">Google</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="headerEle">Logout</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier to use grid.

```css
body{
  background: #eee;
}

#header {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: grid;
  height: 53px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  align-items: center;
}

button.headerEle {
   justify-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img class="headerEle" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/316916526760591362/390814093340311565/unknown.png">

  <a class="headerEle" href="https://www.google.de/">Google</a>

  <button class="headerEle">Logout</button>
</div>
```